# Changing data type in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have county data in which the `"FIP"`s (actually State `"FIP"`s and County `"FIP"`s combined). I have data imported as CSV with the sames `"FIP"`s data titled *'STCounty'*. However, the shapefile `"FIP"`s is listed as a *Real* and the CSV came in as an *Integer* and the Join function does not seem to work.  The drop boxes are greyed out/empty.

So the bigger questions is how do you change the attribute type in a table?

I tried to create a new column in the shapefile (county data) and set it to an integer and then multiply the `"FIP"`s*1, but got a column full of `NULL`.

I am new to QGIS and have a lot of experience in MapInfo, so the join concept is not new to me, just the syntax in QGIS.

Answer (score 15):

Creating a new integer column is the right way to go - but the `1*FIPS` that you used (which would work in Excel or Libreoffice) is where the problem comes in; QGIS doesn't automatically convert between field types in a calculation.

You need to use one of the conversion functions (`toint` converts to integer, `tostring` to text, and `toreal` to real/decimal) with the correct column name:

```
toreal("FIPS")
```

You can use the Tablemanager plugin to then remove unnecessary columns.

Setting up a .csvt file would be the best repeatable solution but for a single column, this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: The 1*FIPS also works in ArcGIS.

Comment: seems kind of silly not to be able to just change the datatype. However, this does seem to be the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

I once answered this question,

If you import your Data from a csv file you need to create a csvt file in order to determine the attribut type of a field.

See the explanation here:
[Changing CSV layer attribute value from text to number in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/how-to-change-an-attribute-value-from-text-to-number/29607#29607)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. In my case i work with Libreoffice and QGIS.

I exported a table from R to **.CSV** with two columns: "id" and "veh". "id" is Integer and "veh" Real.

```
write.csv(tab2,file='/path/table.csv',row.names = F)
```

When i open the **table.csv** in Libreoffice the field veh was read it as "string". So i created another coulmn "vehh" as the multiplication of "veh"*1, and the result was the desired number . Then i saved the file as **.ODS** (Libre Office)

Then i load the **table.ODS** in qgis and "vehh" was recognized as Real.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this and it took me a while to find out that there's a much better, more up-to-date answer to this problem: nowadays, you can use the **Table Refactor Field Tool** from QGIS standard toolbox, it works much better and it's easier.

Basically you go in the toolbox, find the **Refactor Fields** tool, and the popup menu allows you to change the datatype of each field

[image: Table Refactor Field Tool]

See this [link](https://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Change_Attribute_Type) for a step-by-step explanation