# Gduated symbology not taking attribute into account using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-2

I m working on a project on QGIS.

I have a point shapefile vector that represents my store.

In the attribute table, i have bunch of data such as size, unit per transaction and most importantly store turnover.

When I want to graduate the symbology, the turnover isn't present in the list I can choose from.

Does someone know why, and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked what format the fields are in? If turnover is stored as text field then it won't be possible to use it for graduated symbology.

Answer (score 2):

Graduated symbology can only be applied to numerical fields.

If turnover is stored as text field then it won't be possible to use it for graduated symbology.

For ways to change the attribute type see: 
[Changing data type in attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34343/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-in-attribute-table-in-qgis)