# How to prevent QGIS (MMQGIS plugin) from interpreting numbers as strings

Tags: qgis, import, csv

I'm using the MMQGis plugin to "Join Attributes From CSV" into a shapefile and am having trouble getting QGIS to interpret some numbers as numbers (rather than strings which is what its doing).

This is becoming a real problem because the values do not behave like they should when trying to order them, select above a range, etc.

I've seen two somewhat similar questions to this but the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89269/how-to-change-a-csv-layer-attribute-value-from-text-to-number-once-again) instructs the user to import the CSV as a layer. But the CSV data I'm trying to import is not geocoded and I'm using values (things like zip code, etc) to join in the CSVs, so I don't think that question's answers might help here.

Comment: The CSV data does not have to contain coordinates. You can load it using Add delimited text layer if you tick the "no geometries" option.

Comment: You're right. Should I close this?

Comment: You can mark your answer as an answer after the question is a day old. I think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Once the CSV has been joined to the Shapefile, use MMQGis > Modify > Text to Float to convert the appropriate columns