# Matching shapefile to CSV within QGIS - all strings

Tags: qgis, csv

I am trying to link a CSV to a shapefile using the method as described in this tutorial: http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_csv.php

It seems to work fine but the problem is that the CSV when imported in QGIS reads all data as strings. I found a suggestion online to save another file as csvt. In the same location (see [Changing CSV layer attribute value from text to number in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/changing-csv-layer-attribute-value-from-text-to-number-in-qgis)) and I tried using “text wrangler” and  “text edit” but it didn't work out.

Can anyone suggest a solution that works on a MAC (QGIS: 2.4.0-Chugiak)?

Comment: Awesome, glad it works Pama! I will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Field Calculator** to create a new column and then use a similar command like the following in the expression:

```
toreal("your column")
```

for real numbers.

```
toint("your column")
```

for integers.