# Changing census income data from string to number in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to use Census Block group income data that I retrieved from American Fact finder. When I join the income data to the block group shapefile in QGIS it imports as a string.

How can I convert this in to an integer?

Comment: What is the income data? CSV? Excel? I don't understand the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is answered here: [Changing CSV layer attribute value from text to number in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/changing-csv-layer-attribute-value-from-text-to-number-in-qgis)

The [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29607/2315) there, by [@ShepherdJo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8258/shepherdjo) ... reads:

> [...] The answer is that you put a file in the same folder with the
>   ending csvt. For example your file name is xyzdata.csv you add the
>   file xyzdata.csvt
>
> This one you can edit with editor for example. And in it you set the
>   data type like this.
>   "Integer","String","Integer","Integer","String","Real"
>
> Integer is now the variable for the first column, string for the
>   second and so on... Make sure the files are named identically.
>
> Edit: See here too if needed:
>   http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/

Alternatively, if you just have one or two fields you need to convert, you can use the QGIS field calculator to convert a string to a numeric field, as described [in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29629/2315).