# qgis2threejs height of cylinder based on column value

Tags: qgis, 3d, statistics, 3d-map, qgis2threejs

**What i have:**

A csv file with coordinates (RT90)
A Elevation layer

**What i want to do:**

In the csv I have some costs and I want the 3D cylinder to represent the costs.
Higher cost=Higher cylinder

**Problem**
I have no problem rendering the cylinders but i can't control the height.

How do i get the plugin to understand that i want to use a column in the csv to calculate the height?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the field that represents the height (elevation) from the drop-down menu under the `Z-coordinate` section as you can see below:

[image]

It will become like this with a fixed height of 100 under the style.

[image]

If you want to represent the height as dynamic height using also a Z-field of your CSV, you need to choose the same field from the `Height` under the style, as you can see in the first image above, and it will become like this

[image]

Comment: Hi. The problem is that ”Height” isn’t in the drop down. And the values of the ”z” column is fictive.

Comment: There are several issues here. Try to save the CSV file as shapefile and see if that can solve your problem. If not, check if there is any update for the plugin in the plugin manager. I used Point shapefile to create the above 3D

Answer (score 1):

Column type must be number, not string. You need to create a .csvt file or use Delimited Text layer. See "[Changing CSV layer attribute value from text to number in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/changing-csv-layer-attribute-value-from-text-to-number-in-qgis)".