# Defining coordinates cells as "Real" using a .csvt file renders them "NULL"

Tags: qgis, csv

My .csv file was only adding as a 'legend file' in QGIS, and using the 'Properties' tab I saw QGIS regarding all the entries as text.
In order to resolve this, I made the following .csvt file.

```
"Integer","String","Real","Real","Integer","Integer"
```

However, the .csv file still only adds as a 'legend', and using the 'Properties' tab I saw QGIS now regarding the coordinates cells as 'NULL'. All other cells were treated correctly.

How is this possible and how can I resolve this issue?

---

Sample of my .csv file

```
id_tourist;name;latitude;longitude;drift;top_list
1;Dam_Square;52,373056;4,892778;1;1
2;Red_Light_District_&_Oude_Kerk;52,3741183;4,8977614;1;1
3;Rijksmuseum_&_Museum_Square;52,3702157;4,8951679;1;1
4;Westerkerk_&_Anne_Frank_House;52,3750066;4,8837106;1;1
```

Answer (score 3):

So for others out there, use a decimal point instead of a decimal comma when dealing with coordinates.

This a helpful answer explaining how to use .cvst files to define .cvs files:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29607