# Weight from field option not showing all fields from attribute table in heatmap algorithm in QGIS 3.18.1

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to create a heatmap on a shapefile of numerous points based on a single field in their attribute table.

The header of the attribute table is this:

[image: Attribute table header]

... and I want to make a heatmap weighted on the "frp" field from the attribute table. However, in the Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation) settings, I cannot see the "frp" field - only the "longitude" and "latitude" values appear:

[image: Weight from field issue]

What could be wrong here?

Comment: It looks like most of your attributes are strings not numbers, how did you import it?

Comment: It was initially a CSV spreadsheet that I converted to shapefile using ogr2ogr.

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/changing-csv-layer-attribute-value-from-text-to-number-in-qgis help?

Comment: Yep, thank you for the help. They're indeed in string format, which I overlooked, so I'll convert the data types.